# update inline FormSet Django not working, what can i do?

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to create a view to update existing data in the database and in the formset, but my code has no effect.

When I perform a new registration and edit the records, it works correctly.

I realized that I can create and edit up to two records, but if I include a third record, it is not saved.

views.py

```
def atendimento(request):
    form_action = reverse('atendimento:atendimento')
    order_forms = AtendimentoModel()
    item_order_formset = inlineformset_factory(AtendimentoModel, AnamneseModel, form=AnamneseForm, extra=0, can_delete=False, min_num=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            search = int(request.POST.get('clientId'))
            client = ClientModel.objects.filter(pk=search)
        except:
            search = None
            client = None

        updateAtend = int(request.POST.get('updateAtendimento'))
        forms = AtendimentoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=order_forms)
        formset = item_order_formset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=order_forms)

        if updateAtend == 1:
            atendimento = AtendimentoModel.objects.filter(aClient=search).filter(aSituaca='Em Andamento').get()
            forms = AtendimentoForm(request.POST, instance=atendimento)

            anams = AnamneseModel.objects.filter(aIDAtend=atendimento)
            formset = item_order_formset(request.POST, instance=atendimento)
            
        if forms.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            forms = forms.save()    
            formset.save()  
            return redirect('home:index')
    else:
        forms = AtendimentoForm(instance=order_forms)
        formset = item_order_formset(instance=order_forms)

        #inicio de um novo atendimento | BUSCA MÉTODO GET
        try:
            search = int(request.GET.get('searchClient'))
            client = ClientModel.objects.filter(pk=search)
        except:
            search = None
            client = None

        #verifica se há atendimento em andamento
        try:
            atendimento = AtendimentoModel.objects.filter(aClient=search).filter(aSituaca='Em Andamento').get()
            if atendimento.aSituaca != 'Concluído':
                updateAtend = 1
                forms = AtendimentoForm(instance=atendimento)
                anams = AnamneseModel.objects.filter(aIDAtend=atendimento)
                formset = item_order_formset(instance=atendimento, queryset=anams)
            else:
                updateAtend = 0
        except AtendimentoModel.DoesNotExist:
            updateAtend = 0

    context = {
        'form': forms,
        'formAnamSet': formset,
        'name_module': 'Atendimento',
        'form_action': form_action,
        'title': 'Atendimento',
        'client': client,
        'updateAtend': updateAtend,
    }

    return render(request, 'atendimento/atendimento.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class AtendimentoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = AtendimentoModel
        fields = ('aClient', 'aProfessional', 'aLocal','aDataPri', 'aConhece', 
                  'aDifiEsc', 'aDifiPio', 'aOuviMel','aPessFam', 'aTrabRui', 
                  'aTelevis', 'aTeleFix', 'aTeleCel','aConvGru', 'aConvRui', 
                  'aFalaBai', 'aFaladis', 'aCineTea','aPaleSal', 'aOutrDif',
                  'aZumbido', 'aCoceira', 'aOtiteOO','aDorOOOO', 'aCiruOuv', 
                  'aTimpPer', 'aSensTam', 'aOutrOuv', 'aCardiop', 'aPresAlt',
                  'aProbRin', 'aTontura', 'aDiabete', 'aProbTir', 'aUsoOtot',
                  'aColeAlt', 'aLabirin', 'aCancerO', 'aOutrDoe', 'aJaUsoAp',
                  'aMarcaOO', 'aTempoOO', 'aJaTesAp', 'aQualApa', 'aApaIndi',
                  'aValApar', 'aLadoInd', 'aFormPag', 'aSaiTest', 'aRetTest',
                  'aComClik', 'aSemClik', 'aClikOOD', 'aClikOOE', 'aTuboOOD', 
                  'aTuboOOE', 'aReceOOD', 'aReceOOE', 'aSituaca')

class AnamneseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    aAObserv = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3}), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        model = AnamneseModel
        fields = ('aDataAna', 'aAjustOD', 'aAjustOE', 'aAObserv')
```

Models.py

```
CHOICES_OUVIDO = [
    ("OE" ,"Ouvido Esquerdo"),
    ("OD" ,"Ouvido Direito"),
    ("Ambos" ,"Ambos"),
]

class AtendimentoModel(models.Model):
    aClient = models.ForeignKey(ClientModel, verbose_name="Cliente", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    aProfessional = models.ForeignKey(ProfessionalModel, verbose_name="Profissional", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    aLocal = models.ForeignKey(LocalModel, verbose_name="Unidade de Atendimento", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    aDataPri = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data 1ª consulta", null=True)
    aConhece = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aDifiEsc = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aDifiPio = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aOuviMel = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aPessFam = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aTrabRui = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aTelevis = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aTeleFix = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aTeleCel = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aConvGru = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aConvRui = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aFalaBai = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aFaladis = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aCineTea = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aPaleSal = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aOutrDif = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aZumbido = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aCoceira = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aOtiteOO = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aDorOOOO = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aCiruOuv = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aTimpPer = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aSensTam = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aOutrOuv = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aCardiop = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aPresAlt = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aProbRin = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aTontura = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aDiabete = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aProbTir = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aUsoOtot = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aColeAlt = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aLabirin = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aCancerO = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    aOutrDoe = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aJaUsoAp = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=[('sim', 'Sim'), ('não', 'Não')], null=True, blank=True)
    aMarcaOO = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aTempoOO = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aJaTesAp = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=[('sim', 'Sim'), ('não', 'Não')], null=True, blank=True)
    aQualApa = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aApaIndi = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aValApar = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aLadoInd = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CHOICES_OUVIDO, null=True, blank=True)
    aFormPag = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aSaiTest = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    aRetTest = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    aComClik = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=[('sim', 'Sim'), ('não', 'Não')], null=True, blank=True)
    aSemClik = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=[('sim', 'Sim'), ('não', 'Não')], null=True, blank=True)
    aClikOOD = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aClikOOE = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aTuboOOD = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aTuboOOE = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aReceOOD = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aReceOOE = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aSituaca = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=[('Em Andamento', 'Em Andamento'), ('Concluído', 'Concluído')], default='Em Andamento')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.pk} - {self.aDataPri} {self.aClient}'
    
class AnamneseModel(models.Model):
    aIDAtend = models.ForeignKey(AtendimentoModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    aDataAna = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    aAjustOD = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aAjustOE = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    aAObserv = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'ID: {self.pk} - Data: {self.aDataAna} - IDAtend: {self.aIDAtend}'
```

Template

```
    {% load custom_template_tag %}
{% csrf_token %}
<div style="width: 100%;height: 600px;overflow-y: auto;">
    {{formAnamSet.management_form}}
    {% for form in formAnamSet %} 
        <div class="form-row ps-3 pe-3 pt-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group-text d-flex align-items-start">
                    <div class="col-2 ms-1"> 
                        {{form.errors}}
                        <td class="hidden">{{ form.id }}</td>
                        <label for="{{ form.aDataAna.id_for_label }}" class="form-label d-flex align-items-start">{{ form.aDataAna.label }}</label>
                        {{form.aDataAna}} 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-2 ms-1">    
                        <label for="{{ form.aAjustOD.id_for_label }}" class="form-label d-flex align-items-start">{{ form.aAjustOD.label }}</label>
                        {{form.aAjustOD}}  
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-2 ms-1"> 
                        <label for="{{ form.aAjustOE.id_for_label }}" class="form-label d-flex align-items-start">{{ form.aAjustOE.label }}</label>
                        {{form.aAjustOE}} 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-5 ms-1">    
                        <label for="{{ form.aAObserv.id_for_label }}" class="form-label d-flex align-items-start">{{ form.aAObserv.label }}</label>
                        {{form.aAObserv}}  
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-1 mt-5"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button> 
                    </div>   
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
    var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
    var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
    if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
    if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name')
        if(name) {
            name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
        if (forValue) {
        forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
        }
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + prefix + '_set-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', total);
    $(selector).before(newElement);
    var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:first)');
    conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
    .html('-');
    return false;
}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
    var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    if (total > 1){
        btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
        var forms = $('.form-row');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneMore('.form-row:first', 'anamnesemodel');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteForm('anamnesemodel', $(this));
    return false;
});

</script>
```

I looked on several sites but did not find a solution.

Comment: From what I could identify the problem is in the java code, which is not correctly assembling the set, not incrementing a new id code for a new item.